Timelike, spacelike, and lightlike normalization conditions
Let $u^\mu=\frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}$ be particle's "4-velocity" where $\lambda$ is affine parameter. If I am not mistaken, we have, for the different cases:

timelike (massive particles): $u_{\nu}u^{\nu} = g_{\mu \nu}u^{\mu}u^{\nu} = -c^2$
lightlike (massless particles): $u_{\nu}u^{\nu} = g_{\mu \nu}u^{\mu}u^{\nu} = 0$
spacelike (hypothetical tachyons?): $u_{\nu}u^{\nu} = g_{\mu \nu}u^{\mu}u^{\nu} = +c^2$

Here the metric signature is $(-,+,+,+)$.
I have found in the literature that this is called a normalization condition. Does that mean that other normalization are possible? Where does this normalization even come from?
Questions:

Can you confirm the formula are correct?
Are other normalization possible?
Can these normalization conditions taken as axioms or they can be derived?
Could you discuss where these normalization are coming from and derive them from first principles?



FWIW, an affine parameter $\lambda$ is only defined up to affine transformations $\lambda\to a\lambda+b$ where $a\neq 0$. Therefore other normalizations are in principle possible. 2. In the timelike case the 4-velocity is usually defined wrt. proper time.


Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/454886/

I know a nice way to show this with Hamiltonian mechanics, which I will write up as soon as I can sit down in front of my computer. To me,  this is a satisfying approach that is directly from varying the action + some knowledge of phase space.

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/146797/

Depending on the signature, the difference between timelike/spacelike is just that they are of opposite sign. In $(-,+,+,+)$, common to textbooks like MTW Gravitation and such, "timelike" terms in the metric, like $\mathrm{d}t$ and $\mathrm{d}\tau$, usually have a negative sign, while "spacelike" terms in the metric, like $\mathrm{d}x$, $\mathrm{d}y$, $\mathrm{d}z$, etc. have a positive sign.
I'm going to use flat spacetime as an example here; the Minkowski metric in 3+1-dimensional spacetime is
$$\mathrm{d}s^2=-c^2\mathrm{d}\tau^2=-c^2\mathrm{d}t^2+\mathrm{d}x^2+\mathrm{d}y^2+\mathrm{d}z^2=g_{\mu\nu}u^\mu u^\nu$$
in your signature. Here $\mathrm{d}t$ is coordinate time, $\mathrm{d}x$, $\mathrm{d}y$, $\mathrm{d}z$ are coordinate distances, and $\mathrm{d}\tau$ is the proper time, the time experienced by an observer whose worldline has a tangent vector $u$ (which may of course be different from one whose tangent vector in any given frame is $u=0$, which would give $\mathrm{d}\tau=\mathrm{d}t$).
If you define the four-velocity as $u^\mu=\frac{\mathrm{d}x^\mu}{\mathrm{d}\tau}$ (which is how it is often defined), i.e. if your affine parameter is $\tau$ (or, different by a factor of $c^2\approx1$, $s$), then yes, the norm of the four-velocity is what you say it should be, at least in flat spacetime.
Why choose this normalization? Because it's convenient. In fact to be even more convenient we often set $c=1$ which then makes all your normalizations you mentioned $\pm1$. You can pick whatever normalization you want; the only important thing is that you're consistent with it. $c$ is just a speed, and speeds can be whatever you want with your choice of unit systems.
Can this be taken as an axiom? Sure, if you're working in a spacetime where it holds true. I can't immediately think of a spacetime where it doesn't, but then again I can't read the future; maybe one exists and we haven't found it yet. I am not directly aware of a rigorous general proof that this always holds true but it does in all spacetimes I've ever worked with. Generally I would stay away from holding this as an axiom but if I can prove it in my particular spacetime I'm happy to use that as a starting point for other conjectures.
Want to see the proof why $u_\mu u^\nu=c^2$? Simple: using the Minkowski metric, find $\partial_\tau t$, $\partial_\tau x$, $\partial_\tau y$, and $\partial_\tau z$, and then make them into a four-vector and take its norm. Unless I am also terribly mistaken you should get $c^2$.

A comment asks how to prove that $g_{\mu\nu}u^\mu u^\nu=u_\mu u^\nu=c^2$ for spacelike trajectories, so I'll prove that here, starting with timelike trajectories which are infinitesimally more intuitive.
In physical terms, the affine parameter usually used is $\mathrm{d}\tau$ since that makes $u^\mu=\frac{\mathrm{d}x^\mu}{\mathrm{d}\tau}$, which is what is widely used for the definition of 4-velocity as Qmechanic notes. By definition, $-c^2\mathrm{d}\tau^2=g_{\mu\nu}\mathrm{d}x^\mu\mathrm{d}x^\nu$, you can then just divide $\mathrm{d}\tau^2$ and get $-c^2=g_{\mu\nu}\frac{\mathrm{d}x^\mu}{\mathrm{d}\tau}\frac{\mathrm{d}x^\nu}{\mathrm{d}\tau}=u_\mu u^\nu$ for a timelike vector $u$. Trivially you use this process to also arrive at the results that $u_\nu u^\mu=0$ for lightlike vectors (since for such vectors $\mathrm{d}\tau=0$) and spacelike vectors (where $\mathrm{d}\tau^2<0$).

Can you elaborate on how to prove that for spacelike trajectories $x^\mu(\lambda)$, $g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\lambda}=c^2$?

@weeab00 Certainly. It was a bit length for comments so see my updated answer.

Ok here is my tentiative answer based on what I know so far. I can't vouch for the correctness.
Trajectory of massive particles can be parametrized by an affine parameter known as proper time $\tau$ which defined by $ds^2=-c^2d\tau^2$. In a curved spacetime described by a metric $ds^2=g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$, the normalization condition of 4-velocity $u^\alpha=\frac{dx^\alpha}{d\tau}$ of a massive particle is given by $ds^2=-c^2d\tau^2=g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$ from which we get $g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\tau}=-c^2$.
On the other hand photon trajectories cannot be parametrized by proper time because $ds=0$, so it doesn't make sense to define 4-velocity of a photon as $u^\alpha=\frac{dx^\alpha}{d\tau}$. But we can choose some other affine parameter $\lambda$ and define photon's 4-velocity as $u^\alpha=\frac{dx^\alpha}{d\lambda}$. In a curved spacetime described by a metric $ds^2=g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$, the normalization condition for this 4-velocity is given by $ds^2=g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu=0$ from which we obtain $g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\lambda}=0$.
Finally, tachyonic trajectories can be parametrized by proper distance $\sigma$ which is defined as $ds^2=d\sigma^2$. 4-velocity of a tachyon can be defined as $u^\alpha=\frac{dx^\alpha}{d\sigma}$. In a curved spacetime described by a metric $ds^2=g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$, the normalization condition for this 4-velocity is given by $ds^2=d\sigma^2=g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$ from which we obtain $g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^\mu}{d\sigma}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\sigma}=1$ (it is not $g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^\mu}{d\sigma}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\sigma}=c^2$).
